# How to save/acquire Bash post 'eval ' command line string that's about to be executed

Tags: bash, command-line, controls

How do we get/save final command line string accepted and executed by bash right after doing `eval`
very hard to explain, so really helps when xtrace is on, e.g:

```
$ cmd=ls; f=package.o ; eval $cmd $f
+ cmd=ls
+ f=package.o
+ eval ls package.o
++ ls package.o
package.o
```

We see xtrace print out 2nd last string (having dropped prefix ++):

```
 ls package.o
```

which must be in a Bash variable

Comment: Edit  your question to show what you need/expect for *"get/save final command line string accepted and executed"* . `set -x` doesn't lie, but it confuses, 2 `++`s means 2 levels of evaluation occurred (because of the `eval`).

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish here? Do you want this for logging purposes, or to save the command for later execution, or something else? All of these tend to be rather messy to accomplish, and the methods that work well for one goal and situation often don't work for others. See [BashFAQ#50: "I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Comment: So you want to put something into a variable. What do you want to put into which variable? If it is the last word of the last command, this would be the last word in the variable `f` (i.e. after word splitting on `$f`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could redefine `eval` to save its arguments:

```
eval(){
    eval_args=("$@")
    builtin eval "$@"
}
```